# QT sql programming

Tags: qt, qthread, qtsql

include "mythread.h

```
mythread::mythread(int ID, QObject *parent) :
QThread(parent)


{
    this->socketDescriptor = ID;
    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
    db.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
    db.setDatabaseName("mydsn");



    if (db.open())
    {
        qDebug() << "DB is connected!";
        myquery->clear();
        myquery->exec("INSERT INTO phone_table(name_) VALUES ('asdhjs')");
        db.close();
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Db is not connected!" << db.lastError();
    }
}
```

When I insert data its getting error 
Myserver.exe
Myserver.exe has stopped working
Windows is checking for a solution to the problem...
Can anyone help me ?

Comment: what is `myquery`? where is it declared, initialized, etc.?

Comment: @cmannett85, since `myquery` is most likely a member of `mythread` and  since we're looking at constructor, I'd guess that debugger says segmentation fault or so, tracing it to the `myquery->clear()` call ;-)

Comment: I declared myquery in mytread.h QSqlQuery *myquery;

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to initialize your `myquery` object with your database.

Try changing your code to this.

```
if (db.open())
{
    qDebug() << "DB is connected!";

    // Allocate the query object.
    myquery = new QSqlQuery( db ); 
    myquery->clear();
    myquery->exec("INSERT INTO phone_table(name_) VALUES ('asdhjs')");
    db.close();
}
else
{
    qDebug() << "Db is not connected!" << db.lastError();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of your two `myquery` lines:

```
    QSqlQuery q(db);
    q.exec("INSERT INTO phone_table(name_) VALUES ('asdhjs')");
```

Comment: You should probably get more information about the error. like why is it unable to execute.